# How many computational operations is in Sigmoid and tanh activation functions?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am creating a computational graph for LSTM module.

For example, in the case of two rectangular matrices multiplication of a size `A=nxl` and `B=lxm` we can obtain the total number of operations as `Operations(AxB) = n*l*m + n*(l-1)*m` where `n*l*m` is the number of multiplications, `n*(l-1)*m` is the number of additions.

How would I calculate the number of operations (add/substract, mult/div, etc) in Sigmoid and tanh activation functions based on the input size?

Comment: What counts as an operation? For example in sigmoid [1/(1+e^-x)] , does adding +1 counts as operation? Or is just e^-x an operation? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: simple operations: add, substract, mult, division, etc

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess we can discuss. For example for sigmoid if we give nxm matrix as an input, for all elements it will calculate 1/(1+e^-x). So x--> -x  nxm multiplication with -1 , (-x)-->e^-x --> nxm power operation with e,  e^-x-->1+e^-x nxm +1 add operation ,  1+e^-x---> 1/(1+e^-x) nxm division operation. So It means nxmx4 operations are needed  for sigmoid with input nxm matrix. Isn't right?